# Getting autoload paths functionality in a gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I really like how rails autoloads paths in the :root/app directory. I would like to do something similar in a gem I am creating rather than using the explicit ruby autoload everywhere.

Comment: Please give an example of the code you want to replace.

Comment: Are you trying to load all files from a folder or automatically reload files when they change?

Comment: Trying to load all file in a folder hierarchy using rubys autoload. So I am not looking to require the file but rather looking to autoload the files in a dir structure when the constant is called.

Answer (score 3):

[Autoload](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload) defines a mapping from a module (by symbol or string) to a filename.

If you want to autoload all the files in a directory, then you need a way to know what module your file represents without opening it.

You can achieve this by following a naming convention. Assuming you encapsulate your convention in a method `filename_to_module`, then all you need to do is iterate recursively over the folder and call `autoload(filename_to_module(filename), filename)`

Something like this:

```
libdirs = File.join("**", "lib")
Dir.glob(libdirs).each{ |filename| 
    autoload( filename_to_module(filename), filename) 
}
```

I'd use something like [`String#camelize`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/String/camelize) in my `filename_to_module` function. I'd probably implement it myself unless I already had a dependency on `ActiveSupport`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use rails' activesupport.

Add to your gemfile:

`gem 'activesupport', require: 'active_support/dependencies'`

Then you can autoload: `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths += %w[your/path/here]`

credits to Nando Vieira here: https://nandovieira.com.br/usando-o-autoloading-do-activesupport